# How to assign a set of values to another set in clojure

Tags: clojure

if I have a query in Clojure that gives me a set of results, and I need to send these results to a global variable which is a set (it could be empty or have an old values). So, I need to re-assign the results to this global set every time that I have a new results and be able to use them in somewhere else. Anyone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for an `atom`.  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried reset! but it doesn't work, I don't know if I used it with the wright way

Comment: I used this query to give me a set of specific results.

(def result 
     (ekeko [?t] (implements|interface_Method ?t (lvar) (lvar) (lvar))))

after that I defined 

(def s #{})

Comment: I don't know how assign the result to my empty set

Answer (score 2):

If your global is an `atom` e.g.

```
(def global (atom #{}))
```

then you can use `reset!` to change it e.g.

```
(reset! global #{:new :value})
```

if the `global` var is bound directly to a set e.g.

```
(def global #{})
```

you can use `alter-var-root` to update the value in the var e.g.

```
(alter-var-root #'global (constantly #{:new :value}))
```

if you have the choice you should prefer using the `atom`.

Comment: but what if I have a very big set of results, I cannot write them manually, is there is any way to assign results automatically to the global

Comment: That's what functions are for. You can dynamically generate the key/value pairs you need to swap in.

Comment: @user3006595 - Are you trying to incrementally update a set with new values? Please update your question to include details of the problem you're solving and the code you have so far.

Comment: I am doing some predicates using ekeko, and I need every time that I use one of my predicates save part of the results that I get in a specific global var. After that I can use it somewhere else. Because I couldn't do that using ekeko I tried to use clojure. Tell now I know the way that I can update the empty set but I didn't find a way to combine it with my code.